# AngularJS: Binding css properties dynamically

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to bind the css `counter-reset` property dynamically in AngularJS. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4cgexgoc/1/) is fiddle link where you can see what I am trying.

Basically I want the numbering of `li`  elements should start with the number set in the controller. I tried using `ng-style` and `ng-bind-html` to directly bind the style string but still it is not showing the correct output, numbering always starts from 1.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple. [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) expects *an expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys.*

Change your code to be: `<ul ng-style="{'counter-reset': myHtml}">` and you're good to go.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/dboskovic/4cgexgoc/2/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!